# 'Justify-content' property not working with Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

EDIT: Solved via Kameron's suggestion. The problem was that I had set the width on the 'main' element to 50%.

I am trying to get the two child divs of the 'main' element to be centered horizontally.

I have the proper parent container set to my "flex" class, and the two child divs inside. Every other property seems to be working fine, except for `justify content`.

Tried in both flex directions. Also tried checking in 3 different browsers - same behaviour. The content stays aligned to the left.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  max-width: 120rem;
  min-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main class="main flex">
  <div class="main__description">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main__hours">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the expected result ? And justify-content only apply to the direct child items of the flex container, it won't work if what you are trying to justify are the h2 / p elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have `width: 50%;` on the `.main` which is only instructing this container to use half of the screen. To fix this, add `margin: auto;` to `.main` to center the parent.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<main class="main flex">
  <div class="main__description">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main__hours">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Another option:**

Make the `.main` container `width: 100%;` so that `justify-content: center;` places it in the center of the screen, and not in the center of 1/2 of the screen.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="main flex">
  <div class="main__description">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main__hours">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

**Side note**: remove the `min-width` on `body` if you want this to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The two `div`s are actually aligned correctly, but their content (`h2` and `p`) is not. A simple solution would be to set `text-align: center` to the `<main>` element, or adding `display: flex` to the two `divs` aswell:

```css
.main__description,
.main__hours {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```